# Alinhamento Footer

Tags: html, css

Estou fritando meus neuronios e até agora não cheguei em uma solução. Estou montando uma pagina, mas não tem jeito do footer alinhar na pagina. Na minha maquina resolvi, mas se abre numa tela maior o footer fica na metade, em um celular ou tablet também. A pagina e o css estão nesse link. Alguma ideia?

O index e o css estão aqui: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/h6pfh6133mwsgpm/AABMZZNXt3V51FlK6TdparXUa?dl=0

O teste da pagina aqui: http://www.venuzka.url.ph/

Alguém tem uma ideia?

Comment: O único conteúdo dessa página vai ser o banner?

Comment: Não, tem os sliders no meio e o problema é o footer que não se alinha conforme a resolução da pagina, o resta ele alinha tudo :(

Comment: RESOLVIDO, alterei o tamanho da imagem do topo e resolveu. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

Este problema é devido à colocação do footer no teu ficheiro index.php .
O footer está dentro do ID `#container`

No final da página remove tudo desde a linha 144 até ao final, que é desde: (`<div id="footer">`) até (`</html>`) e cola o código modificado no qual eu vou referir abaixo.

**Código atual:**

```
<div id="footer">
        <br>
            <p> Suporte: <a href="mailto:diego.venuzka@peccin.com.br?subject=Suporte%20-%20SIG">Clique Aqui </a></p>
            <p>&copy; Peccin 2011 - 2014. Website Designed by <a href="mailto:diego.venuzka@peccin.com.br">TI - Peccin</a></p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Modifica para:**

```
</div> <!-- isto fecha a div #container antes de começar o #footer -->
    <div id="footer">
        <br>
            <p> Suporte: <a href="mailto:diego.venuzka@peccin.com.br?subject=Suporte%20-%20SIG">Clique Aqui </a></p>
            <p>&copy; Peccin 2011 - 2014. Website Designed by <a href="mailto:diego.venuzka@peccin.com.br">TI - Peccin</a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Depois disto se ainda quiseres que o footer seja centralizado é só fazer as alterações no teu ficheiro  `styles.css` modificando para:

```
#footer {
    background-color: #010101;
    height: 80px;
    width: 1800px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    margin-left: auto; /* linha modificada */
    margin-right: auto; /* linha adicionada */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Algum script esta criando um  após fechar o .
um jeito simples seria criar um script para conseguir chegar nesse objetico e apagar ele com css, ve se isso funciona:

```
<script>
$("object[type='application/gas-events-uni']").css({
overflow:'hidden',
display:'none'
})
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Isso está ocorrendo por que o footer está configurado como estático.
Inclua esse css no footer:

.footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}

Comment: Obrigado amigo, mas não deu, ele continuou igual :(

Comment: Vai no seu arquivo onde está o css, procuro o seu id que é #footer, altere "position:relative" para "position:absolute", altere também "width:1800px" para "width:100%" e inclua mais uma linha como "bottom:0"

Comment: Ele alinhou no rodape, beleza, mas o tamanho lateral dele ainda fica menor :( Ele alinha na seta da direita praticamente, ai fica um baita espaço em branco

Comment: Então faça as seguintes alterações: na div footer você coloca o width:100% e position:absolute, não precisa incluir o bottom. Nos parágrafos dentro da div, você retira o margin-left, e altera o text-align:left para text:align: center

Comment: Tentei, mas olha como ficou: https://www.dropbox.com/s/trhjicla3n5fzax/foto.PNG?dl=0

Comment: vocẽ colocou o width:100% na div footer?

Answer (score -1):

Você pode fazer o que o @MarcosPeres sugeriu, ou pode criar um código com jQuery para identificar o tamanho da tela do usuário e atualizar a altura minima do conteúdo da sua página.

No seu caso você poderia fazer mais ou menos assim:

```
function updtSize($) {
   var mheigth = $(window).height();  // Altura da janela
   mheight -= $("#header").outerHeight(true); // remove a altura do header
   mheight -= $("#nav").outerHeight(true); // remove a altura do menu
   mheight -= $("#footer").outerHeight(true); // remove a altura do footer
   mheight += $("#slides-container").height() - $("#slides-container").outerHeight(true); // remove as margens do footer

   $("#slides-container").css('min-height', mheight); // o mheight agora tem só a altura necessária para o footer encostar no bottom
}


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   updtSize($);
   $(window).resize(function(event) {
      updtSize($)
   });
});
```

Comment: Amigo, não entendi, teria que criar um js com o teu codigo?

Comment: Isso, tenta colocar esse script antes do fechamento da tag `body`.

Comment: Basicamente o que esse script faz é colocar uma altura mínima que sua tag `slides-container` tem que ter para que a tag `footer` encoste no rodapé da página.

Answer (score -1):

Faça o seguinte :

```
div#slides-container {
height: 250px;
overflow: hidden;
width: 960px;
padding-top: 40px;
margin: auto;
}
```

Retire a div footer dentro da container e faça o seguinte

```
<div id="w_footer>
 <div id="footer"></div>
</div>
```

no css faça o seguinte:

```
#w_footer{
 widht:100%;
 barckground-color:#010101;
}

#footer {
background-color: #010101;
height: 80px;
width: 85%;
margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: Tentei amigo tua dica, olha como ficou... https://www.dropbox.com/s/bund1baekisnbae/foto2.PNG?dl=0

Comment: desculpe tem um erro, veja a edição que fiz. O banner já está centrado.

Comment: Fiz tudo que voce me disse amigo, inclusive obrigado pela ajuda, mas olha na imagem, parece que tem algo "bloqueado" o footer, não tem explicação... https://www.dropbox.com/s/j4hv9f68cg0ucrq/foto3.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Por favor, coloque o código html e css na pergunta. Também acho que deve mudar os tópicos css e html, pois isto nada tem de php.

Comment: Desculpe, já tirei o PHP. Sobre os codigos nao postei por serem extensos, mas ok, irei editar e postar eles aqui.

Comment: Eu verifiquei o código e está correto. Deve ter algum erro na edição que fez. Retire Também o width dos p do footer.